# How to inject property to base class using Typhoon

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have class structure such as:

```
class BaseNetworkClient: NSObject {
    var defaultParametersBuilder: DefaultParametersBuilder!
}

class NetworkClient: BaseNetworkClient {

}

class DefaultParametersBuilder: NSObject {

}
```

And Typhoon Assembly

```
class CoreComponentsAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {
    dynamic func baseNetworkClient() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(BaseNetworkClient.self) {
            (definition) in
            definition.scope = .ObjectGraph
            definition.injectProperty(#selector(self.defaultParametersBuilder), with: self.defaultParametersBuilder())
        }
    }

    dynamic func networkClient() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(NetworkClient.self) {
            (definition) in
            definition.scope = .ObjectGraph
        }
    }

    dynamic func defaultParametersBuilder() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(DefaultParametersBuilder.self) {
            (definition) in
            definition.scope = .ObjectGraph
        }
    }
}
```

BaseNetworkClient doesn't inject to any class but NetworkClient inherits from it. The problem is I can't inject any property to BaseNetworkClient. Properties are always nil. What's wrong?

Comment: Try in networkClient() definion.parent = baseNetworkClient()

Comment: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#abstract-and-base-definitions

Comment: Thanks guys! Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract and Base Definitions are described in the project wiki: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#abstract-and-base-definitions

To inherit an injection you need to set parent for definition:

```
definition.parent = self.baseNetworkClient()
```

Assembly will change as follow:

```
dynamic func baseNetworkClient() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(BaseNetworkClient.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.injectProperty(#selector(self.defaultParametersBuilder), with: self.defaultParametersBuilder())
    }
}

dynamic func networkClient() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(NetworkClient.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.parent = self.baseNetworkClient()
        definition.scope = .ObjectGraph
    }
}
```